# How to indicate the authentication URL in OpenAPI 3.0?

Tags: openapi

Defining a Bearer authentication scheme in OpenAPI 3.0 is straightforward:

```
components:
  securitySchemes:
    bearerToken:
      type: http
      scheme: bearer
```

But this doesn’t tell the API users how to actually get a token.

Is there a way of saying ”you need to provide a token in order to use this API, and you can get one by doing a POST request at `/api/auth` with fields `login` and `password`”?

(I guess I could document the `auth` endpoint, but then I would have to drop the global `security` property and instead put it under every endpoint except that `auth` one, right?)

Answer (score 0):

You can still have the global security setting be token auth, and then override it for /api/auth to allow un/pw combo for token generation